# DOT net Factory ArrayList From String Split

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I am trying to directly assign the String split to an array list .I am not succeeding it .Is it right way of doing it?

```
Set A1=DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("System.Collections.ArrayList")
A1=Split(A B C)
A1.Capacity
```

A1 assigns as an array variant .Can't perform any ArrayList Methods like sort ,indexof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the items to the arraylist. (You shrould not directly assign an array to an arraylist)

```
Set A1=DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("System.Collections.ArrayList")
A1.addRange(Split("A,B,C", ","))
```

'Now A1 has all the items. Now you can call any arraylist methods in QTP.

```
A1.Capacity
A1.Sort
A1.Reverse
```